# How to build a qid/group matrix for XGBRanker?

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, ranking

I have a list of items that are hits and decoys, and have to rank the items in the active group.

I'm not allowed to post everything (unfortunate for making a minimally working example), but the key parts are `items`, which is just a numpy ndarray of strings, and `active_or_not` which looks like `array([1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0])` which is the same length as `items`

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# unfortunately I can't post everything, but the key parts are below:

ranker = xgboost.XGBRanker(
    objective='rank:pairwise',
    learning_rate=0.1,
    n_estimators=100,
    max_depth=3,
    gamma=1.0,
    subsample=0.5,
    colsample_bytree=0.5,
    min_child_weight=1,
    reg_alpha=0.5,
    reg_lambda=0.5,
    base_score=0.5,
    random_state=42,
    n_jobs=-1
)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(items, active_or_not, test_size=0.2)
xgb_rank = ranker.fit(X_train, y_train, group = list(range(len(X_train))))
```

when I run this code, I get an error

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 620, in inner_f
    return func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 1931, in fit
    train_dmatrix, evals = _wrap_evaluation_matrices(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 448, in _wrap_evaluation_matrices
    train_dmatrix = create_dmatrix(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 908, in _create_dmatrix
    return DMatrix(**kwargs, nthread=self.n_jobs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 620, in inner_f
    return func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 743, in __init__
    handle, feature_names, feature_types = dispatch_data_backend(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xgboost/data.py", line 952, in dispatch_data_backend
    _check_data_shape(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xgboost/data.py", line 62, in _check_data_shape
    raise ValueError("Please reshape the input data into 2-dimensional matrix.")
ValueError: Please reshape the input data into 2-dimensional matrix.
```

I am not an expert with machine learning, and I don't know if `XGBRanker` is appropriate for this task.

How can I make a 2-dimensional matrix for this? the online documentation at https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html isn't very helpful

the table that they give is

```
qid   label   features
1      0      x_1
1      1      x_2
1      0      x_3
```

but how can I make a table like that for a list like I have? Again, I don't know if `XGBRanker` is appropriate.